# Receive error when trying to post on Twitter using ShareKit

Tags: cocoa-touch, twitter, oauth, uinavigationcontroller, sharekit

I'm trying to use sharekit to post on Twitter and Facebook.

I have two buttons which call the following two methods:

```
- (IBAction) shareOnFacebook:(id)sender
{
    // Create the item to share 
    NSString *someText = @"Share on Facebook.";
    SHKItem *item = [SHKItem text:someText];

    // Share the item
    [[SHK currentHelper] setRootViewController:self.navigationController];
    [SHKFacebook shareItem:item];
}

- (IBAction) shareOnTwitter:(id)sender
{
    // Create the item to share 
    NSString *someText = @"Share on Twitter.";
    SHKItem *item = [SHKItem text:someText];

    //tried both methods to set navigationcontroller!
    [[SHK currentHelper] setRootViewController:self.navigationController];
    [SHK setRootViewController:self.navigationController];  

    [SHKTwitter shareItem:item];
}
```

Facebook is working only, when I try to use Twitter I get the following error:

```
2011-05-31 10:20:25.928 App[870:707] *** Assertion failure in -[SHK showViewController:], /Users/blaat/Dropbox/App/Classes/ShareKit/Core/SHK.m:112
2011-05-31 10:20:25.975 App[870:707] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'ShareKit: Could not find a root view controller.  You can assign one manually by calling [[SHK currentHelper] setRootViewController:YOURROOTVIEWCONTROLLER].'
```

Which is strange because I use the same method for Facebook to set the NavigationViewController where everything is working...
I checked all the variables over and over again in the SHKConfig.h

- Authentication OAuth
- Application Type "Browser"
- Callback url filled in the same in config and in dev.twitter.com
- Consumerkey OK
- Consumersecret OK

Anyone an idea?

Edit. I enabled debugging for Sharekit and this was the result. I still don't see where the problem is.

```
2011-06-01 09:07:28.496 App[179:707] <0x2e9400 OAMutableURLRequest.m:(242)> OAMutableURLRequest parameters oauth_consumer_key=****************&oauth_nonce=9C826DA5-A991-4045-BA6C-96D62CF09AA0&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=1306912048&oauth_version=1.0
2011-06-01 09:07:30.109 App[179:707] <0x2e4240 SHKOAuthSharer.m:(108)> tokenRequestTicket Response Body: oauth_token=tsuRQUGI63sE7XnRyxiNgy4G03ycUG7G0KhEjhROuw&oauth_token_secret=jIsb6rqhqf11neREsIVrCnjy9i7epLhDKROmjgYJDmQ&oauth_callback_confirmed=true
2011-06-01 09:07:30.578 App[179:707] *** Assertion failure in -[SHK showViewController:], /Users/blaat/Dropbox/App/Classes/ShareKit/Core/SHK.m:112
2011-06-01 09:07:30.774 App[179:707] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'ShareKit: Could not find a root view controller.  You can assign one manually by calling [[SHK currentHelper] setRootViewController:YOURROOTVIEWCONTROLLER].'
*** Call stack at first throw:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x33cd264f __exceptionPreprocess + 114
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x34115c5d objc_exception_throw + 24
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x33cd2491 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 68
    3   Foundation                          0x34be4573 -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 62
    4   App                                 0x0000bd5f -[SHK showViewController:] + 722
    5   App                                 0x0000fe87 -[SHKOAuthSharer tokenAuthorize] + 238
    6   App                                 0x0000fbb5 -[SHKOAuthSharer tokenRequestTicket:didFinishWithData:] + 396
    7   CoreFoundation                      0x33c42571 -[NSObject(NSObject) performSelector:withObject:withObject:] + 24
    8   App                                 0x00015cb5 -[OAAsynchronousDataFetcher connectionDidFinishLoading:] + 208
    9   Foundation                          0x34ba02f5 -[NSURLConnection(NSURLConnectionReallyInternal) sendDidFinishLoading] + 68
    10  Foundation                          0x34ba0277 _NSURLConnectionDidFinishLoading + 78
    11  CFNetwork                           0x369ba411 _ZN19URLConnectionClient23_clientDidFinishLoadingEPNS_26ClientConnectionEventQueueE + 136
    12  CFNetwork                           0x369aef45 _ZN19URLConnectionClient26ClientConnectionEventQueue33processAllEventsAndConsumePayloadEP20XConnectionEventInfoI12XClientEvent18XClientEventParamsEl + 100
    13  CFNetwork                           0x369af0cd _ZN19URLConnectionClient26ClientConnectionEventQueue33processAllEventsAndConsumePayloadEP20XConnectionEventInfoI12XClientEvent18XClientEventParamsEl + 492
    14  CFNetwork                           0x369aee37 _ZN19URLConnectionClient13processEventsEv + 70
    15  CFNetwork                           0x369aede9 _ZN13URLConnection24multiplexerClientPerformEP18RunLoopMultiplexer + 36
    16  CFNetwork                           0x369aed5b _ZN17MultiplexerSource7performEv + 126
    17  CFNetwork                           0x369aecd9 _ZN17MultiplexerSource8_performEPv + 8
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x33ca9a79 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 12
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x33cab75f __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 382
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x33cac4eb __CFRunLoopRun + 230
    21  CoreFoundation                      0x33c3cec3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 230
    22  CoreFoundation                      0x33c3cdcb CFRunLoopRunInMode + 58
    23  GraphicsServices                    0x347a541f GSEventRunModal + 114
    24  GraphicsServices                    0x347a54cb GSEventRun + 62
    25  UIKit                               0x33789d69 -[UIApplication _run] + 404
    26  UIKit                               0x33787807 UIApplicationMain + 670
    27  App                                 0x000023af main + 70
    28  App                                 0x00002364 start + 40
)
```

Edit: I got the answer

```
[SHK setRootViewController:self.navigationController];
```

needs to be:

```
[SHK setRootViewController:self];
```

Problem was that it needed a `UIViewController`, while I was passing a `UINavigationViewController`.

Answer (score 3):

We use ShareKit as well. We haven't run across this one yet, but according to the [docs online](http://getsharekit.com/support/#issues), ShareKit will try to use the navigation controller stack to find your root view controller, then pop a modal view controller from there. It throws this error when it can't find one.

You can correct it by manually setting the root view controller by using the following call:

```
[SHK setRootViewController:myViewController];
```

Comment: I was doing that only I was passing a UINavigationViewController instead of a UIViewController

Answer (score 2):

Edit: I got the answer

```
[SHK setRootViewController:self.navigationController];
```

needs to be:

```
[SHK setRootViewController:self];
```

Problem was that it needed a UIViewController, while I was passing a UINavigationViewController...